# Use of instantiation in enum

Tags: c

I was studying enum and i came across instantiation of enum variable in code. But enum works perfectly fine without instantiation as in this code:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
enum year{Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul,Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec}; 
int main() 
{ 
   int i; 
   for (i=Jan; i<=Dec; i++)       
      printf("%d ", i); 

   return 0; 
}
```

and the output is:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

So what is the use of declaring a variable and that to in enum type. If i want, i can declare it in int or float which works perfectly fine. this might be a naive question but i am unable to get the practical applications of this feature.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
enum week{Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri, Sat, Sun}; 
int main() 
{ 
    enum week day; 
    day = Wed; 
    printf("%d",day); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `Jan` is clearly (?) a month, `0` is... what is it again? Why is it in the code? Same thing for the datatype. `year` is clear, `int` is not. But in your examples you should have used different names for the enums. Like `month` and `week_days`.

Comment: You could stop using `int` from today and use only `long int` as it would fit all `int`s. Give a read to [this link](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/newbie#enumeration-is-its-own-type).Also there is a provision to define `enum` without giving it a name. But there can be cases like where it could get confusing for the reader.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca enums are named numbers, and in general case, they start from 0. What is the issue with that? Enum value is irrelevant as long as it's unique, `Jan` could be "0" like right now or "42" and it would mean exactly same thing.

Comment: @Sahsahae if you asked me "what day of the week is it today?" would you prefer me to answer "sunday" or 0? It's exactly the same day, but "sunday" is more meaningful. It's not a problem with syntax, it's a problem of making what you mean clear.

Comment: I still fail to see the issue, if they needed to print actual day name, they would create a static array of `char*`'s that would directly map enum values (which are completely irrelevant to you, as you have variable names which are readable), to readable strings.

Comment: I think you're misreading my comment and answer. Or maybe I didn't make myself clear enough. That "what is it again? why is it in the code" is meant from the perspective of someone reading the code and finding, for example, a function call like `set_month(0)` which would be a lot more clear if it was `set_month(Jan)`.

Answer (score 3):

`Jan` is clearly (?) a month, `0` is not clear at all.

Then, supposing you chose meaningful names, it also work as a type annotation. `year` is clear (or it would be, if a good name is chosen), `int` is not. In your examples you should have used different names for the enums. Like `month` and `week_day`.

Finally, in your example they are not meant to represent an integer value (unless you need that for calculations, like difference between months). So it doesn't make a lot of sense simply printing them as numbers.

Comment: Do you not know what C enums are or are you asking them why their enum value is 0, when it's perfectly valid?

In either case, -1 because you don't really explain anything about enums nor why they can directly assign enum value to int/float.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you getting at. I'm not asking why it's 0. I'm saying that "Jan" is more clear than 0 when talking about months.

Comment: Yeah, that's why we use enums to begin with, how does that have anything to do with the question? They cannot print literal "Jan", because "Jan" is variable name that points to 0. printing value of "Jan" is not the issue.

Comment: And where did I say it is?

Answer (score 2):

See below example to understand how `enum`s may be quite helpful.

Please also note how easy you could add more fruits. You in fact just only need to add it the `enum`s definition and to the name arrays as is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

enum Fruit
{
  Fruit_Undefined = -1,  

  Apple,
  Orange,
  Pear,

  Fruit_Maximum
};

const char * names_of_fruits[Fruit_Maximum] =
{
  "Apple",       
  "Orange",
  "Pear",
};

const char * get_name_of_fruit(enum Fruit fruit)
{
  const char * result = NULL;

  if (Fruit_Undefined >= fruit || Fruit_Maximum <= fruit)
  {
    errno = EINVAL;
  }
  else
  {
    result = names_of_fruits[fruit];
  }

  return result;
}

int main(void)
{
  for (enum Fruit fruit = Fruit_Undefined;
    fruit <=  Fruit_Maximum;
    ++fruit)
  {
    const char * name = get_name_of_fruit(fruit);
    if (NULL == name)
    {
      perror("get_name_of_fruit() failed");
    }
    else
    {
      puts(name);
    }
  }
 }
```

Compile it, run it and get:

```
get_name_of_fruit() failed: Invalid argument
Apple
Orange
Pear
get_name_of_fruit() failed: Invalid argument
```

Sure this can be completely done via `int`s and `define`s as well.

Comment: Minor quibble on terms: (UV anyways) `Fruit_Maximum <= fruit` as an error looks wrong.  Having the maximum value is not wrong, have a value exceeding the maximum is. Perhaps `Fruit_N`?

Comment: @chux: C wise you are right, `Fruit_Maximum` (and `Fruit_Invalid` as well) are valid values for `enum Fruit`. Application-level wise the `Fruit_Invalid` and `Fruit_Maximum` are not a fruit. I introduced them to not have the need to use any "real" fruits when dealing with boundaries. And `Fruit_Invalid` as well can be used as a "null"-fruit, as an "unknown" fruit. `Fruit_Unknown` might have been a better name though.

Comment: @chux: Rethinking the naming, I feel you are right: `Fruit_N` suites better then `Fruit_Maximum`.

Answer (score 2):

Enumeration types make it easy-ish to model categories of things that aren’t necessarily ordered, like

```
enum fish {salmon, tuna, cod, halibut, grouper};
enum genre {drama, comedy, action, horror, scifi};
```

You can use enumeration constants without having to create an object of that type - it’s kind of handy for modeling error codes and things like that.

Yes, you *could* model these things using regular integer constants:

```
const int salmon = 0;
const int tuna = 1;
...
```

or preprocessor macros:

```
#define SALMON 0
#define TUNA 1
...
```

Enumeration types just make the process a little easier and a bit more intuitive.

It should be pointed out that C’s enumeration abstraction is “leaky”.  Ideally, an object of type `enum fish` should *only* be able to take on values specified in the enumeration (which is the case in newer languages like Java).  However, because C’s enumeration types are basically `int` under the hood, an object of type `enum fish` can take on *any* `int` value, so it’s not as useful an abstraction as it could be.

Answer (score 1):

`Enum`erations are used to enumerate something, just like you have the code that allows you to enumerate days without caring what the real values of variables are, as long as you don't modify them yourself, they all will be unique, which is what you want.

Enums in C are integral type, and because C does not really have a strong typing system, it automatically casts enum value to `int` or `float`, that's why you can do that, but correct code should not do that.

You use enums when you want to have different types of something, without bothering to assign values yourself...

For example, just like in your code, you can create variable names for all months, and value of these variables is not important, you just know that Jan is Jan, and here's that. It's value can be anything, a 0, -42, or even 4564798. The only thing that's important is that every time you use `Jan` somewhere, value will be the same.

Comment: In fact IIRC the type of an enum constant is defined to be `int` rather than the enum type it's from.

Comment: That's what I mean by `integral`, just me saying that way detaches from any implementation possible. I don't remember anything preventing enum from being a `short`, or `long long`, these types can be cast to other numeric types, including floating point values.